# Drupal new theme creation

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I am new to drupal. I have created a new drupal theme. my theme affected drupal page. If I click add Content page,Content page not formatted. I am not able to add the content in my new theme.
here I have paste page--front.tpl.php file.

```
    <div id="wrapper">
              <header id="header">
                <div class="section clearfix">
                <div class="logo_left">
                    <?php if ($logo): ?>
                        <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" rel="home" id="logo">
                            <img src="<?php print $logo; ?>" alt="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" />
                         </a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
               </div>
               <nav class="logo_right"><?php print render($page['header']);?></nav>

              </div></header> <!-- /.section, /#header -->  

                <div id="menu">
                    <!--ul>
                         <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Client</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul-->

                    <?php print render($page['header_menus']); ?>

                </div>

                    <div id="content">
                            <div id="leftcontent">
                                     <div id="flash">

                                  </div>
                    <div id="leftcontent1" >
                           <div class="rightcontentheader"> <h2>CLIENT REPORTING</h2></div>
                        <?php print render($page['block_one']); ?>      
                    </div>
                    <div id="leftcontent2">
                     <div class="rightcontentheader">  <h2>AUTOMATED MARKETING</h2></div>
                        <?php print render($page['block_two']); ?>      
                    </div>  



                            </div>





                            <div id="rightcontent">
                                        <div id="rightconent1">
                                          <div class="rightcontentheader"> <h2>REAL ROI IMPACT</h2></div>
                                                <?php print render($page['galery_right']); ?>       
                                         </div>
                                     <div id="rightconent2">
                                          <div class="rightcontentheader"><h2>LATEST NEWS</h2></div>
                                                <?php print render($page['block_three']); ?>        

                                     </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
     <div id="footer">
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Kindly list all the files that exist inside your theme directory

Answer (score 0):

You will need a page template file called `page.tpl.php`. In there you can define your layout. If that file is not found, drupal falls back to it's default theme. (unformatted but including all content).

On the [drupal site](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!tests!themes!block_test_theme!page.tpl.php/7) you can find this default `page.tpl.php` file. I'd suggest you start editing from there, leaving all php variables in place. Removing a variable results in part of the page not beïng loaded.

**UPDATE**
Sorry that link is for Drupal 5, perhaps you can better use a file of one of the shipped templates.

**Update 2**
Updated the link to Drupal 7. You will have to click the "view source" button right above the comments

Comment: thanks for your reply.I have created page--front.tpl.php.but same issue occur.Could you please check it.

Comment: do you have html.tpl.php there that is actually including a stylesheet? Is there are CSS file in your theme folder and is it in the theme.info file? Those are the last things I can think of.

Comment: thanks for your reply.I have include my css file in html.tpl.php and include css file in .info file also but i'not able add content in my new create theme.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding your question. Have you set the maintenance page to your template? It's at the bottom of http://www.yoursite.com/admin/appearance . That's the last thing I can think of.

Comment: No,I have not set any maintenance page to my theme.My issue is new theme reflect my drupal site.I click apearance and structure link work properly(page format good.)but I am click add content link page format problem occur.

Comment: I meant maintenance theme, but the link was good. It is strange. Perhaps page-node-edit.tpl.php is wrongly loaded? (try removing it if you have it), or dump the cache. Also you could disable the theme and then re-enable it. That way possible new template files will be re-scanned.

Comment: I'm having node.tpl.php file.Could I remove it?as per suggestion I clear cache and disable the theme and re-enable it.But the issue not solve.

Comment: give it a shot, you can change the extension so the system won't understand and ignores the file. Then disable the theme completely (change to other theme, disable yours, re-enable yours and set default).

Comment: I have tried as per your suggestion.but the issue not solve.my new theme affect all the pages like(structure,appearance,configuration)but the content add page problem occur and also login page not formatted.